# Applying map on tensorflow Dataset performs very slowly

Tags: python-3.x, performance, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I work with **Tensorflow 2.2** in **python 3.8**. I have a Dataset object build of tensor slices and need to apply some computation, call it `compute`, on each tensor of the dataset. To this end I use the `map` functionality of `tf.data.Dataset` (see below for the code). The map, however, performs rather slowly compared to direct application of the given method on each tensor. Here is the model case (the code below is saved in a file called `test.py`).

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @tf.function
    def compute(self, tensor):
        # the main function that performs some computation with a tensor
        print('python.print ===> tracing compute ... ')

        res = tensor*tensor
        res = tf.signal.rfft(res)  # perform some computationally heavy task

        return res

    def apply_on_ds(self, ds):
        # mapping the compute method on a dataset
        return ds.map(lambda x: self.compute( x ) )

    @tf.function
    def apply_on_tensors(self, tensors):
        # a direct application on tensors of the compute method
        for i in tf.range(tensors.shape[0]):
            res = self.compute(tensors[i] )
```

To run the code above, stored in `test.py`, I do the following

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import time

import test

T = test.Test()
tensors = tf.random.uniform(shape=[100, 10000], dtype=tf.float32)
ds      = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensors)

t1 = time.time(); x = list( T.apply_on_ds(ds) );  t2 = time.time();
# t2 - t1 equals ~1.08 sec on my computer

t1 = time.time() ;  x = T.apply_on_tensors(tensors);   t2 = time.time();
# t2 - t1 equals ~0.03 sec on my computer
```

> Why is there such a massive gap in performance between applying the
> `map` and applying the same function used for map directly ?

When I add `num_parallel_calls` and `deterministic` parameters of the `map` setting to correspondingly `8` (number of cores on my machine) and `False` the process runs in `~0.16 sec` (vs. `~1 sec` without parallelization). Nevertheless, this is still significantly worse than the direct application of the method used in `map`.

Is there any apparent mistake I am doing here? I suspect there is some retracing of the graph in place when using the map, however, I could not find an evidence for that. Any explanation of the above and suggestions for improvement would be much appreciated.

Comment: the related issue on github https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40755

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am answering my question, just in case someone might encounter the same problem described in the question. What follows is based on the comments on this [Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40755) (more information is available therein).

There is no problem with the code itself. The gap in performance is because the `map` operation (op) is placed and executed on **CPU** while the one-by-one application of the function used in the `map` is taking place on **GPU**, hence the difference in the performance. To see this, one can add

```py
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
```

to the code to access the information on where Tensorflow places its operations.
To force the `map` to execute on GPU, one can take the computation of the `compute` method inside the

```py
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
```

block (see the link above).

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Only problem is that you can't prefetch the data into the GPU as of now, wasting much time in the cpu->gpu->cpu data transfer